# SQL Server : stored procedure infinite loop

Tags: database, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, infinite-loop

What will happen to a database server if I execute a stored procedure that contains an erroneous condition, causing an infinite loop? Is there any way for the DBA to detect such a sitution and halt it ?

Comment: Why, sounds like you are doing something a little naughty

Comment: This post shows no research or effort to answer the question on your part.

Comment: Of course you should check any code you write that has a loop to make sure it is not going to go into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

> What will happen to a database server if I execute a stored procedure that contains an erroneous condition, causing an infinite loop?

It depends on the query ..query may consume more resources,may cause blockings and many things can happen

> Is there any way for the DBA to detect such a sitution and halt it ?

DBA can check for long running queries and kill this query